# Getting error undefined type or module when defining struct for diesel models

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I can't get diesel to run on Rust. The background of this project is a score counting system using postgres as a server to save the scores and diesel to access postgres. When I define a struct in models.rs (named `Score`), I get this error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `scores`
 --> src/models.rs:7:16
  |
7 | #[table_name = "scores"]
  |                ^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `scores`
```

The contents of schema.rs is:

```
table! {
    scores (name) {
        name -> Varchar,
        points -> Nullable<Int4>,
        subject -> Nullable<Varchar>,
    }
}
```

Here is my models.rs:

```
#[macro_use]
use diesel::*;
use diesel::sql_types::*;
use crate::schema::scores::*;

#[derive(Queryable, Insertable, QueryableByName)]
#[table_name = "scores"]
pub struct Score {
    #[sql_type = "Varchar"]
    name: String,
    #[sql_type = "Integer"]
    points: Option<i32>,
    #[sql_type = "Varchar"]
    subject: Option<String>,
}
```

I'm trying to add entries to it using add_entry.rs:

```
use super::models::Score;
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use crate::schema::*;

pub fn create_score(conn: PgConnection, name: String, score: i32, subject: String) -> () {
    let new_score = Score {
        name: name,
        points: Some(score),
        subject: Some(subject),
    };   

    let ins = diesel::insert_into(scores::table)
        .values(new_score)
        .execute(&conn);
}
```

In main.rs, I have:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate diesel;
mod add_entry;
mod connect;
mod models;
mod schema;
use diesel::dsl::sql_query;

fn main() {
    let conn = connect::connect();
    let name = String::from("name");
    let subject = String::from("subject");
    add_entry::create_score(conn, name.clone(), 75, subject.clone());
    //random data
    list_score();
}

fn list_score() {
    let connection = connect::connect();
    let result = sql_query("SELECT * FROM scores");
    println!("{:#?}", result);
}
```

And in connect.rs(to connect with server) I have:

```
use dotenv::dotenv;
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use diesel::prelude::*;
use std::env;

pub fn connect() -> PgConnection {
     dotenv().ok();
     let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL")
         .expect("Cannot get DB URL.");
     PgConnection::establish(&database_url)
         .expect(&format!("Error connecting to {}", database_url));
}
```

The contents of the dependencies section of my Cargo.toml is

```
dotenv = "0.9.0" 
diesel = { git = "https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel", features = ["postgres"] }
```

To get this error, I ran `diesel setup` to set up everything, `diesel migration run`, `diesel migration redo`, `diesel migration run` again, and finally `cargo build`.

My full code can be found in this [repository](https://github.com/Steph2709/Scores_MRE).

What should I do to remove this error?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you compile your code? What commands do you type, and what are the contents of your `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: I compiled by using `cargo build`, and the contents of my Cargo.toml is ```dotenv = "0.9.0"
diesel = { git = "https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel", features = ["postgres"] }```

Comment: I found out that the line causing this could be `#[derive(Queryable, Insertable)]`, but I don't know how I should fix it. I require this line to be able to query it and insert into it. So what should I do?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in http://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/? I.e. you generally need to run `diesel setup`, create a database, write some migrations for a table with a corresponding name etc. You should call your type `Score`, so the table name is inferred as `scores`. You probably also don't want to use an `i8`, since there is no corresponding Postgres data type.

Comment: I did follow the steps in the "Getting Started" guide in diesel.rs as you wrote. What integer type would be accepted by postgres? So would changing the struct name fix this? I'll try changing the struct name to the table name when I can to see if that works.

Comment: I can use i16 as integer in postgres right? Since postgres only support minimum of 2 bytes for integers(as `smallint`).

Comment: I can confirm that changing the `struct` name to `scores` doesn't fix the error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: [To make Stack Overflow a useful resource for future visitors beyond the context of your repository](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380194/155423), please [edit] your question to add a [MRE] in the question itself, in addition to the link to your repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You need to import `use crate::schema::scores;` instead of `use crate::schema::scores::*;`.

Longer explanation:

Diesel's `table!` macro generates a quite complex module structure, containing several types. Additionally those types are reexported from different locations, for example the `dsl` module. The derive needs to know the `crate::schema::your_table::table` type and all types for each column (so `crate::schema::your_table::column_a`, …). As it cannot access the whole module and has not knowledge about what types are in scope, diesel needs to infer that type somehow. The simplest way to do this is getting the module name from somewhere. That is done via the `#[table_name = "your_table"]` attribute, which assumes that a module `your_table` is in scope that contains the corresponding types for table and columns.

For more details checkout the following documentation:

- [Insert Guide](https://diesel.rs/guides/all-about-inserts/)
- [Documentation for `table!` macro](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.3/diesel/macro.table.html)

Answer (score -1):

If your schema contains nullable fields you need to use an `Option<T>` on rust side for such field:

```
#[macro_use]
use diesel::*;

use crate::schema::scores;

#[derive(Queryable, Insertable)]
//#[table_name = "scores"]
pub struct Score {
    //#[sql_type = "Varchar"]
    pub name: String,
    //#[sql_type = "Integer"]
    pub points: Option<i32>,
    //#[sql_type = "Varchar"]
    pub subject: Option<String>,
    //#[sql_type = "Varchar"]
    pub date: Option<String>,
}
```

And when using `diesel::insert_into` remember to import `schema::scores`.

`add_entry.rs`:

```
use super::models::Score;
use crate::schema::scores;
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use diesel::prelude::*;

pub fn create_score(
    conn: PgConnection,
    name: String,
    score: i32,
    subject: String,
    date: String,
) -> () {
    let new_score = Score {
        name: name,
        points: Some(score),
        subject: Some(subject),
        date: Some(date),
    };

    let ins = diesel::insert_into(scores::table)
        .values(new_score)
        .execute(&conn);
}
```

If you fix the problem that arise from using a moved value into `main.rs` you can now compile your project.

```
add_entry::create_score(
    connection,
    option.clone(),
    scores,
    subject.clone(),
    date.clone(),
);
```

Comment: I'll try this and report back later. Thanks

Comment: I still get the same error even though the contents of my `models.rs` is exactly the same as the one you wrote. I already changed the name of the `scores` column in the table, the migrations, and the schema to `points`.

Comment: Could it be because I tried using SQL queries instead of the queries provided in the diesel guides? I tried implementing `QueryableByName` to do this, which in turn required `#[table_name = "scores"]`. This caused the error to turn on `#[table_name = "scores"]`.

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't change anything. Can I also ask why I can't seem to use the normal code to query from the database. To query I use this code:`let average = sql_query("SELECT AVG(score) FROM scores");`. Could this be connected to the problem? I can't even use `.load()` on this code for some reason like in the examples [here](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/fn.sql_query.html).

Comment: I meant `let result = sql_query("SELECT * FROM scores");`. Sorry

Comment: @StephenTaharuddin My random guess is that you omitted `mod schema` or `use schema::*` or something along these lines. Please provide a minimal reproducible example if you want more than a random guess. :)